# How to sign in in Pyrogram only by phone number Telgram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-api, pyrogram

app = Client.sign_in("phone_number")

How to sign in in Pyrogram only by phone number
without api_hash and api_id

Comment: what have you tried so far ? where is the code ?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**
You have to generate yours from here https://my.telegram.org/apps

Or if you are lazy use those of another Telegram client as everyone does, but you should generate your own.

```
API ID: 6
API HASH: eb06d4abfb49dc3eeb1aeb98ae0f581e
```

*On google you can easily find those of other clients as well.*